# How to store a (dictionary) object in JavaScript localStorage?

Tags: javascript, json, object, local-storage

I have a very simple dictionary .

```
var meta = {'foo':'1','moo':'2'}
```

I want to store this in the local storage and retrieve it.

```
 window.localStorage.setItem("meta", meta);
 var meta1 = window.localStorage.getItem("meta");
 alert(meta1['foo']);
```

The above does not work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`localStorage` converts it's input to strings, so you will have to convert your objects to JSON strings, and back:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("meta", JSON.stringify(meta));
var meta1 = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("meta"));
alert(meta1['foo']);
```

---

The reason your code didn't work is because setting a object in `localStorage` sets it's value to `"[object Object]"` (`object.toString()` returns `"[object Object]"`):

```
window.localStorage.setItem("objectInput", {some:"object"});
var objectOutput = window.localStorage.getItem("objectInput");
alert(objectOutput);
// This returns "[object Object]"
```